# Problem with farsi language in usecase's scenario

Tags: uml, farsi

I'm using [Enterprise Architect 8](http://www.sparxsystems.com.au/products/ea/8/index.html) software to design our compan`s UML diagrams. But I can not use the Persian(Farsi) language in my usecase's scenarios. When i save scenarios, the sentences reversed.

for example : when I try to save following sentece in scenario part

سلام پطوری
it showen:
چطوری سلام

Please give me some suggestion to fix this problem or alternate softwares which supports UML 2.3 and Persian language.

Thanks

Comment: Wow! what does that say?

Answer (score 0):

this is because of the difference,between the keyboard layouts,in some cases the location of Persian "پ" is not the desired,or expected location that,Iranian always using,you can fix it using this DLL file

> KBDFA.DLL

[here is](http://www.farsipardaz.com/) the website that created this DLL.

if you want use a software that is not support the Persian keyboard,there are some solutions for this,you can use the free Lemoon software,[Here is the link](http://www.softgozar.com/WebPage/SoftwareDescription.aspx?SoftwareId=660&Title=%D8%AF%D8%A7%D9%86%D9%84%D9%88%D8%AF%20%D9%81%D8%A7%D8%B1%D8%B3%DB%8C%20%D9%86%D9%88%DB%8C%D8%B3%DB%8C%20%D8%AF%D8%B1%20%D9%81%D8%AA%D9%88%D8%B4%D8%A7%D9%BE) to that software

there is another solution for fixing the keyboard layout:you can use the Keyboard Layout Manager software and change your keyboard layout.